# PHP-Jade to PHP output error

Tags: php, pug

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to translate this PHP into passable JadePHP format.

```
<a <?php e($p->isOpen(), ' class="active"') ?> href="<?php echo $p->url() ?>"><?php echo $p->title()->html() ?></a>
```

Here is my current Jade structure, this needs to go right in the  tag
nav(role="navigation")

```
nav(role="navigation")
  ul(class="menu cf")
    - foreach($pages->visible() as $p):
    li
      a(href!="<?php echo $p->url() ?>")
        = $p->title()->html()
      - if($p->hasVisibleChildren()):
      ul.submenu
        - foreach($p->children()->visible() as $p):
        li
          a(href!="<?php echo $p->url() ?>")
        - endforeach
       - endif
    - endforeach
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `a(class="<?php e($p->isOpen(), \"active\") ?>" href="<?php echo $p->url() ?>") <?php echo $p->title()->html() ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last version of https://github.com/pug-php/pug, simply do that:

```
nav(role="navigation")
  ul(class="menu cf")
    each p in pages.visible()
      li
        a(href!=p.url())
          =p.title().html()
        if p.hasVisibleChildren()
          ul.submenu
            each a in p.children().visible()
              li
                a(href!=a.url())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use php echoes if you are using jade/pug PHP version.

You must to send to output using jade syntax: `#{$p->url}`

Follow issues channel on github to know some of pug and its updates.